# pg_config executable not found on windows 10

Tags: python, postgresql, dll

I have installed PostgreSQL. I think I need to install libpq-dev on windows to solve this issue, But how to install it?

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
running egg_info
creating pip-egg-info\psycopg2_binary.egg-info
writing pip-egg-info\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
<http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably already have it installed, it is just not on your `PATH`.

You could use `SET` on the command line to change the path so that `pg_config` is on it.